# Where do offline changes in a OneDrive/Word document go?

Tags: microsoft-word, onedrive

trying to help an end-user friend recover some lost writing à la 1995. Windows 10 Home, Office 365 Word, low-grade laptop. File in question was already large and had gone through a great deal of editing.

It may be relevant to point out that the file was set to AutoSave. If [this MSFT agent comment](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/changes-made-to-word-doc-offline-were-lost-during/ba16c314-7fc3-49a1-be7a-832a8a400434) is correct that "it cannot save anything without the network", well, I'd like to know more about that...

Here as I understand it is the sequence of events:

1. While online, the file is closed and presumably synched to cloud.
   Word may or may not have been closed.
2. Offline a short time later, file is opened and confirmed to have latest (online) changes
3. Editing and new text mid-document ensue, including much compulsive CTRL+S
4. Still offline, file is closed (saved)
5. A short while later, back online, opens file, changes do not appear

OneDrive shows three versions, they appear to be identically missing changes despite differences in time. The Windows Explorer last-modified property shows the correct time, i.e. Windows appeared to do the right thing locally in step 4.

Any ideas what might have happened, or where to look for a recoverable something? (No, I am not referring to AutoRecover, nothing broke application/OS-wise, just a readable cache of some kind.)

Comment: There is a folder called `"C:\OneDriveTemp\[YOUR_USER_SID]"` but it is immediately deleted once OneDrive finished transferring the file. Contrarily to what you said, AutoRecover could help you recover your file in your case, isn't it ? Did you check inside this folder ?

Comment: Word stores temporary saves in `%AppData%\Roaming\Microsoft\Word`. You could also look in the Recycle Bin.

Comment: @Christopher There are files in there, but none of the dates are late enough to match--I think this OneDrive instance is probably stuck dirty and needs to be relinked, but one step at a time. Is there a way to read the files decrypted? Might help others for whom the case works

Comment: @harrymc Found the folder (%appdata% is roaming though), no luck there either filetime-wise. There *is* a STARTUP folder in there that seems to match the timing on step 5, but it's empty :/

Comment: I'm fresh out of ideas. Hopefully someone else will step in.

Answer (score 1):

Late update: we stumbled onto a solution to this the other day, because it came up again how annoying it is to have the work seem to vanish, and the old derelict file was still sitting there (the ol' copy all the text over to a new doc and move on with life), and it was maddeningly simple:

*copy the file out of OneDrive to a standard Windows location* and the text returns as if by magic (because, hypothesis: Word, not OneDrive, is now managing version conflicts, which weren't there in the first place).